# Evaluate value to true, if value is

Tags: javascript

A check like `if (value)` evaluates to ***true*** if value is ***not***:

- null
- undefined
- NaN
- empty string ("")
- 0
- false

I want

1. to invert this check: evaluate to ***true***, if value ***is***:

   - null
   - undefined
   - NaN
   - empty string ("")
   - 0
   - false
2. to combine it (OR) with another check, whether my variable begins with given character, like `if (a.indexOf("b") === 0)`

I tried it on this way:

```
if (!(a) || a.indexOf("b") === 0){
...
}
```

But something is wrong there. What is the best way to make such check?

**PS**: don't know why, but this (and similar) constructions, like `a[0] ==='b'` are don't work for me - they don't catch the case (tried it with console. The only working is `a.indexOf("b") === 0`

**PPS**: again, don't know why, but brackets were preventing expected work. This one works:

```
 if (! a || a.indexOf("b") === 0){
    ...
    }
```

Comment: What is wrong here ? your explanation about `!a` is correct, and you can combine it with a `||` . However, remember that the negation of A OR B is (NOT A) AND (NOT B)

Comment: do you have some examples of `a` and the wanted results?

Comment: your attempt looks correct by what you explain you need. If `a` is not false then fall back to checking if `a.indexOf('b') === 0`.

Comment: @AdamCopley - don't know why, but the thing was in brackets. Your very first variant, from deleted post, does the job.

Comment: @Evgeniy Your code mentioned in PPS (`!a || a.indexOf("b") === 0`): (1) `a = 1234` will break (2) `a = ['b']` will be true. Just remember this ;)

Answer (score 0):

Read: if `a` is not truthy or the first character of `a` is `'b'`.

```
if (!a || a[0] === "b") {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss check on 'a' type:

```
if (!a || (typeof a === 'string' || Array.isArray(a)) && a[0] ==='b'){
    ...
}
```

Comment: can you provide any references for this method?

Comment: "`boolean b = (n == 0) || (m/n > 2);` Even if n is zero this line will never cause a division by zero, because the left hand side is always evaluated first. If n is zero then the left hand side is true and there's no need to evaluate the right hand side. Mathematically this makes sense because m/0 is in some sense infinite which is greater than two." (Source http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/46.html) - I doubt javascript works in different way. I wouldnt say it is missed check... but its preferable.

Comment: https://ponyfoo.com/articles/null-propagation-operator
references for method

Comment: @David Renne - I understand what you mean, it makes sence, but must to say that here is no division by zero (indexOf('b') returns index of first occurrence of 'b' in string or array a). Thats why a moment later i add type check on string or Array

Comment: You have edited in a way I can not complain anymore... now we still need to know if `['b']` is considered `true` or `false` - you seem guessing `['b']` is in wanted range :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
  // with check ['b'] => true
  if (!a || `${a}`[0] ==='b'){
      // triggers when a is
      // null, undefined, NaN, "", 0, false, 'b'
  }

  // with check ['b'] => false
  if (!a || typeof a === 'string' && a[0] ==='b'){
      // triggers when a is
      // null, undefined, NaN, "", 0, false, 'b'
  }
```

Check here how it evaluates:

```js
// dosnt filter ['b']
function checkA(a) {
    console.log('type a', a, (!a || `${a}`[0] ==='b'));
}

// considered true
checkA(null)
checkA(undefined)
checkA(NaN)
checkA("")
checkA(0)
checkA(false)
checkA('b')
checkA(['b'])

// considered false
checkA('a')
checkA('c')
checkA([])
checkA({})
checkA(123)

// also filter ['b']
function checkB(a) {
    console.log('type b', a, (!a || typeof a === 'string' && a[0] ==='b'));
}

// considered true
checkB(null)
checkB(undefined)
checkB(NaN)
checkB("")
checkB(0)
checkB(false)
checkB('b')

// considered false
checkB(['b'])
checkB('a')
checkB('c')
checkB([])
checkB({})
checkB(123)
```